# C enumerated types name scoping

Tags: c, enums

GCC tells me you can't use the same names for separate enumerated type values, e.g.

```
enum flag_one {
    SUCCESS,
    FAIL
}

enum flag_two {
    SUCCESS,
    FAIL
}
```

is not allowed by the compiler. So scoping is not 'witihin' the enum definition?

Is the approach to do something like:

```
enum flag_one {
    FLAG_ONE_SUCCESS,
    FLAG_ONE_FAIL
}

enum flag_two {
    FLAG_TWO_SUCCESS,
    FLAG_TWO_FAIL
}
```

Slightly confused as I like using enums for return integer codes as its more readable/descriptive but I'm already starting to get name clashes

Comment: Why do you need to make two enums? It's not as if the compiler is going impose any type checking on your enums.

Comment: i'm using an enum per function to define the set of allowable return ints and give them sensible names. seemed to make sense until i hit this problem with name clashes, I assumed scoping would mean that you couldn't have similar names within the same enum but similar names acros separate enums would be fine. I think I have misunderstood how enums work

Comment: i think having several enums makes reading helps simplify reading of the code, i.e. the return ints and their descriptions are grouped per function. If I slapped it all in one enum it would be a big long enum and you would lose the ability to see which return ints belonged to which function

Comment: but, if the constants share the same values and meaning (success/fail or alike) what's the point? put the enum in a .h, include and use it consistently... if the meanings differ, names should differ too...

Comment: This is a C question.  It's not as if C has C++'s `::` scoping operator.  Even if scoping worked the way you thought, how would you possibly resolve ambiguity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So scoping is not 'witihin' the enum definition?

No. This is not allowed. Enumerator lists define constants. Your `enum`s happen to be in the same scope -- the *file scope*. You cannot have two constants with the same name *within the same scope*.

From the draft of CX:

> **6.7.2.2 Enumeration specifiers**
>
> **Semantics**
>
> **3** The identifiers in an enumerator list are declared as constants that have type int and
>   may appear wherever such are permitted.127) [...]

Also, from footnote 127 (which is technically non-normative and for informational purposes only):

> 127) Thus, the identifiers of enumeration constants declared in the same scope shall all be distinct from
>   each other and from other identifiers declared in ordinary declarators.

.

> Slightly confused as I like using enums for return integer codes [...]

Use `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` defined in `stdlib.h`.

Comment: if the enums were in different files would you use the static keyword to ensure they were in different 'file-scope'?

Comment: `enum` is a type, so `static` (or any storage duration) doesn't make any sense.

Comment: just revisiting this issue, similar enum constant names in same file is a no go, but if in separate files is it OK or not OK (I will test this now as well..)

Answer (score 3):

The enum values are visible in the scope of the enum type. That means they have to be unique in that scope.

Some other language, like C++11, have added a new kind of emums `enum class` where the values are not directly visible in the enclosing scope.

You would then have to write `flag_one::SUCCESS` and `flag_two::SUCCESS` to get the values, so it's not a huge difference from your second option.